# What is the permutation of word "MISSISSIPPI"?

Tags: probability, permutations

> What is the total no. of permutations of the letters of the word *MISSISSIPPI* in which no four "*I*"s come together?

My try-:  $7!/4!\times 2! \times 8!/4!$

But not getting the right answer.

Please help

Comment: show your work.

Comment: do you want none of the I's to be together or just want not all 4 together? In the sense, is it okay to have MISSIISSPPI?

Comment: @AnuragA "No four I come together" is quite clear, they just should not all 4 group together. For this restriction just subtract the number of permutations of MYSSSSPP, where Y represents the forbidden group IIII.

Answer (score 3):

Number of permutations of the word *MISSISSIPPI* in which no $I$'s are together =Number of permutations of the word *MISSISSIPPI*-Number of permutations in which $4$ I's are always together

$\dfrac{11!}{4!2!4!}-\dfrac{8!}{2!4!}$

Comment: I think OP wants no I's to be together. Not just all 4 I's not together. His wording is a bit confusing.

Comment: @AnuragA The OP says "No four 'I' come together", I think its safe to assume that the only permutations which are not wanted are the ones which contain all $4$ adjacent I.

Comment: @Ovi Perhaps you are right but it almost looks like he could have meant none of the four I's are together, which would alter the question completely.

Comment: Let the OP clarify it and then we all again will come into business

Answer (score 3):

Just put all the i's together.

Total number of permutations =$\dfrac{11!}{4!2!4!}$. and total number of permutations in which all i's are together=$\dfrac{8!}{2!4!}$.

Just subtract and get the answer.

i.e$\dfrac{11!}{4!2!4!}-\dfrac{8!}{2!4!}$.